# How to make this route parameter working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const { redirect } = require("express/lib/response");
const { forEach } = require("lodash");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neq";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque..";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien.";
let posts = [];

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home",{startingContent:homeStartingContent,posts:posts});
  
    
})

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about",{aboutContent:aboutContent});
})

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.render("contact ",{contactContent:contactContent});
})

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
})

app.post("/compose", function(req,res){
  const post = {
    title:req.body.postTitle,
    content:req.body.postBody
  };
  posts.push(post);
  console.log(posts)
  res.redirect("/");
})

app.get("/posts/:postName",function(req, res){
  const requestedTitle = req.params.postName;
  posts.forEach(function(post){
    console.log(requestedTitle);
    const storedTitle =req.body.postTitle; 
    console.log(storedTitle);
    if(storedTitle===requestedTitle){
      console.log("match found");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Not a match");
    }

  });
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I am having issue with  `app.get("/posts/:postName",function(req, res){` and  `const storedTitle =req.body.postTitle;`
The issue is whenever I run http://localhost:3000/posts/Test in browser I am suppose to get output as match found but when I console log storedTitle to debug  I get it as undefined istead of Test.
output screenshot:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZcTB.png)
These are pictures of /compose ejs file.
[compose.ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYG4f.png)

Comment: `app.get("/posts/:postName",...` is  not present in the provided code. Is that intentional?

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu - really?

Comment: @Bravo, what do you mean?

Comment: @Bravo, it's been edited :-). I am pretty sure I have scrolled.

Comment: it was there in the original unreadable wall of green text :p

Comment: @Bravo, okay! I must have missed it.

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu - so did I to be honest :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `const storedTitle =req.body.postTitle;` you should use `const storedTitle = post.title;`

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` in log because, of the following lines:

```
const storedTitle =req.body.postTitle; 
console.log(storedTitle);
```

Because, `GET` requests does not have `body`.

Change those lines as follows:

```
const storedTitle = post.title; 
console.log(storedTitle);
```

I suppose it is a copy/paste error from `/compose` handler :-)

Good day!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `req.body` in a GET request
It should either use POST
`app.post("/posts/:postName",....`

or

`const storedTitle =req.query.postTitle;`